# Test if soft keyboard is visible using espresso

Tags: android, android-espresso

I want to test keyboard visibility when an activity calls onCreate() and onResume().

How can i test whether or not the keyboard is shown using espresso?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I know, that the question is old enough, but it doesn't have any accepted answer though.
In our UI tests we use this method, which uses some shell commands:

```
/**
 * This method works like a charm
 *
 * SAMPLE CMD OUTPUT:
 * mShowRequested=true mShowExplicitlyRequested=true mShowForced=false mInputShown=true
 */
fun isKeyboardOpenedShellCheck(): Boolean {
    val checkKeyboardCmd = "dumpsys input_method | grep mInputShown"

    try {
        return UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation())
            .executeShellCommand(checkKeyboardCmd).contains("mInputShown=true")
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        throw RuntimeException("Keyboard check failed", e)
    }
}
```

Hope, it'll be useful for someone

Comment: what is `UiDevice` ? what library is that coming from?

Comment: This is from UiAutomator library. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/uiautomator/UiDevice

Comment: Great, this works and doesn't seem to have an issue if editText is focused but keyboard is closed.

Comment: It worked, but is really slow for some reason. Saket's answer was much faster

Answer (score 7):

```
fun isKeyboardShown(): Boolean {
    val inputMethodManager = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
    return inputMethodManager.isAcceptingText
}
```

found at [Google groups](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-platform/FyjybyM0wGA/7gycld7-gtIJ)

Comment: This did not work for me. It returned true when an input was focused, but the keyboard was hidden.

Comment: Also doesn't work for me. Always returns false, even if `EditText` is in focus

Comment: didn't work for me... return true always (edit text has focus)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the standard insets APIs to assert that the soft keyboard is visible.

```kotlin
view.rootWindowInsets.isVisible(WindowInsets.Type.ime())
```

If you're using [compose-ui-test](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/testing), you can use its `waitUntil { }` API:

```kotlin
@get:Rule val rule = createAndroidComposeRule<TestActivity>()

rule.waitUntil {
  rule.activity.window.decorView.rootWindowInsets.isVisible(WindowInsets.Type.ime())
}
```

Comment: This only works on API 30+ (`WindowInsets.Type.ime` and `WindowInsets.isVisible` were both introduced in API 30), any idea how to make it work on earlier versions?

Comment: For < API 30 you can use `ViewCompat.getRootWindowInsets()`

Comment: Thanks, it worked. Note to others: you need to use `WindowInsetsCompat.Type.ime()` with this one

Answer (score 0):

another trick could be checking for the visibility of a view that you know is going to be covered when the keyboard is showing. don't forget to take animations into consideration...

instrumentation testing using espresso and hamcrest for the NOT matcher something like:

```
//make sure keyboard is visible by clicking on an edit text component
    ViewInteraction v = onView(withId(R.id.editText));
    ViewInteraction v2 = onView(withId(R.id.componentVisibleBeforeKeyboardIsShown));
    v2.check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    v.perform(click());
    //add a small delay because of the showing keyboard animation
    SystemClock.sleep(500);
    v2.check(matches(not(isDisplayed())));
    hideKeyboardMethod();
    //add a small delay because of the hiding keyboard animation
    SystemClock.sleep(500);
    v2.check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Comment: With Espresso, sleep() should not be needed. Instead you should use an IdlingResource. Also, `Espresso.closeSoftKeyboard()`.

Comment: Animations should be turned of using Espresso for testing, to ensure everything is working properly.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
private boolean isSoftKeyboardShown() {
    final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivityInstance()
           .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    return imm.isAcceptingText();
}
```

Java version of @igork's answer.

Answer (score 0):

This method is working for me

```
val isKeyboardOpened: Boolean
    get() {
        for (window in InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().uiAutomation.windows) {
            if (window.type == AccessibilityWindowInfo.TYPE_INPUT_METHOD) {
                return true
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```

Comment: It did not work, it returns false even if the keyboard is open