# Espresso: Toggle Network State

Tags: android, kotlin, network-programming, android-espresso

I am currently working on an Espresso test suite that covers offline functionality. In order for me to implement these tests, I need to create a method that I can call to toggle on/off network connectivity. So far, I have been able to toggle WiFi, but I have not been able to figure out how to turn off cellular data.

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: @Shaishav this worked for me: 
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/23646/how-can-i-switch-on-off-airplane-mode-and-wifi-using-appium?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Is any of this related to Coded UI which is part of Microsoft's Visual Studio? If not then please remove the misleading tag(s).

Comment: @DillonC how did you do it using espresso? I know you said it worked for you but that link that you shared is for Appium

Comment: A recent answer below indicates that this question is a duplicate of an older question: [Testing internet connectivity error handling in Android Studios with Espresso on Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39759395/testing-internet-connectivity-error-handling-in-android-studios-with-espresso-on) (It is a settled guideline here that answers should not be given if an identical answer is available on another question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution worked for me:
https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/23646/how-can-i-switch-on-off-airplane-mode-and-wifi-using-appium?answertab=votes#tab-top

You can also perform a *really* jank workaround. 
Note: I did this mainly for fun, do not promote the actual use of it ;)

```
#!/bin/bash

### SET Airplane Mode ON ###
adb shell am start -a android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS \
&& for i in {1..5}
do 
    adb shell input keyevent 20
done \
&& adb shell input keyevent 23 \
&& adb shell input keyevent 4;

### Run tests ###

### SET Airplane Mode OFF ###
# NOTE: When Airplane Mode is enabled in API 28, "Mobile network" is disabled. Additionally, since Android Setting's Network & internet 
# is still running in the background, you'll have to select the down action two less times. 
adb shell am start -a android.settings.AIRPLANE_MODE_SETTINGS \
&& for i in {1..3}
do 
    adb shell input keyevent 20
done \
&& adb shell input keyevent 23 \
&& adb shell input keyevent 4;
```

Comment: Can you share Espresso code how to activate offline mode?